# In fragment caching, what does the action_suffix mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I read the API on Rails caching and while I understand the big picture of how fragment caching works, I'm confused by the action_suffix part.

```
<% cache(:action => "list", :action_suffix => "all_topics") do %>
```

Do we use the action_suffix if the list action has multiple fragments that we're caching?  Can someone give an example of how they used the action_suffix option?

Answer (score 0):

1) yes for multiple fragments per action
This default behavior is limited if you need to cache multiple fragments per action or if  the action itself is cached using caches_action.

after using action_suffix

the url would be /controller_name/list/action_suffix

**Note that the URL doesn’t have to really exist or be callable**

Please let me know if this answer is sufficient or not

Comment: Hi Raja, thanks for responding.  I've read something like what you're saying here but I still find it vague. I think I would understand it best if I saw an example.